# Are there good tools for debugging, profiling, tracing in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, debugging, profiling

If I want to debug queries on SQL Server, I'll use the profiler built into SQL Studio Management Studio. Do similar tools exist for MySQL?

I'm aware of [showing running queries](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/show-running-queries-mysql/), [profiling CPU usage per query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html), and other techniques, but because I'm going to be spending a lot of time working on query performance over the coming weeks, I'm wondering if tools exist to streamline the debugging process. Both commercial and open source solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) ([Query Profiler](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/query-profiler.html) and Session Manager tools).

Also have a look at [Debugger for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/code-debugger.html).